# My Website Downloads MP4s Instead of Plays them

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I have a website I am working on and I have an uploads/ folder with mp4 files. When I test this site locally using XAMPP and click the link to the MP4 files, Chrome plays the MP4 with the browser and then when I click the back button it takes me back to my site. When I upload all of the site files to a webserver and click the same links to view the mp4 files it downloads the files and keeps me on the same page. However, I would like it to perform the same actions it does when I am developing locally, and play them, not download the files.

Is it possible to have Chrome play Mp4 files that are hosted on a server and not download them?

Answer (score 1):

Brad is correct. You need to look into something called **MIME types**, they tell your server how to deal with different kinds of file extensions. It sounds like .mp4 is enabled already on your local XAMPP so just need to set it on your live server.

On a shared Apache/Linux web server you manage these through the **.htaccess** file, simply add the following lines into the .htaccess file:

> **AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v**
>
> **AddType audio/mp4 .m4a**

On an IIS/Windows server you manage these via HTTP Headers > Files Types > MIME Map.

> Type in **.mp4** as the extension and **video/mpeg** as the content type.

If you're not able to add the above because you don't have the appropriate admin permissions, check with your hosting company, or use jquery or similar external method like ivan suggested.

Comment: Don't use `.htaccess` for stuff like this if you can help it.  Edit the server's configuration.  By using `.htaccess`, your server has to re-parse that stuff for every request.  If you just edit the configuration, it's only parsed once.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your server is sending the wrong content type.  You should probably be using `video/mp4` for this content.  Otherwise, your server typically defaults to `application/octet-stream`, which is a generic type that your browser will save to a file.

I can't give you specifics for how to configure your server since you didn't say what server you're using, but it's a basic config task for most servers.

Comment: Where would I put the video/mp4, as an attribute in the anchor tag linking to the video on the server?

Comment: No, in your server's configuration

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use HTML5 video tag but IE8 doens't support it. Following an example:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
  </object>
</video>
```

Comment: HTML5 video isn't relevant to this question, but is a valid alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If I were You I use Jquery for play mp4.

Example:

```
$('.media').media();

<a class="media" href="sample.mov">My Quicktime Movie</a> 
<a class="media" href="sample.swf">My Flash Movie</a> 
<a class="media" href="sample.wma">My Audio File</a> 

<div class="media"> 
    <object codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" 
        classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"> 
        <param name="src" value="sample.mov"> 
        <embed src="sample.mov" 
            pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"></embed> 
    </object> 
    <div>My Quicktime Movie</div> 
</div> 

<div class="media"> 
    <object codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7" 
        classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
        type="application/x-oleobject"> 
        <param name="src" value="sample.swf"> 
        <embed src="sample.swf" 
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
            pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed> 
    </object> 
    <div>My Flash Movie</div> 
</div> 

<div class="media"> 
    <object codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" 
        classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" 
        type="application/x-oleobject"> 
        <param name="url" value="sample.wma"> 
        <embed src="sample.wma" 
            type="application/x-mplayer2" 
            pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed> 
    </object> 
    <div>My Audio File</div> 
</div>
```

Check this link out to get the plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/media/

Comment: There is no need for all this.  HTML5 video is quite compatible these days, and for mobile has much better compatibility than Flash.  Many browsers support MP4.